# How to change the tool for the "open in external editor"?

Tags: netbeans, ide

Simply it may sound, but when I try to open a graphical file using the "Open in external editor.." by the right-click context menu in the "projects" view - nothing happens. 
Can somebody explain to me, how is this option supposed to work? The default program associated with graphical files (in this case it's a .png) is GIMP, buth NetBeans seems to be missing that fact. Also here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image]

The version of Netbeans I use is 8.1 and my operating system is Arch Linux.

Answer (score 2):

One way that I have been able to do it in NetBeans 8.1 (on Windows) is to right click on the file in the Projects view. Then select the Tools-->Send To...-->Configure... sub-menu. That will bring up another window with the "Send To" tab of the "Miscellaneous" tab selected.

In that window, select the "Add" button. Enter a name (whatever you want) in the "Script Name" form field. Select "Script that accepts file(s) as parameters" in the "Script Type" pull down. Enter "${SHELL}" (without the quotation marks) in the "Script" form field. In the field below that, enter the path to your editor with a space followed by "$@" (e.g., "Emacs $@" without the quotation marks).

Then, right click the name of the new script that you created in the "Scripts List" and select the Tools-->Add to Palatte... option.

Finally, right click your source code file in the Projects view and select the Tools-->Send To...-->. That will then open the file in your editor.

UPDATE: The aforementioned approach only seems to work with Ant (not Maven) based projects. Since I recently started utilizing almost exclusively Maven based projects, the aforementioned approach is now useless to me. Thus, I did more research and am now using the [QuickOpener plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/62668/quickopener).

The [QuickOpener plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/62668/quickopener) is not quite as convenient as the aforementioned approach, but it is sufficient.